# How to generate a random group of result from a list

Tags: python

So, In a exercice of my school, 'cell' is a point that have his own coordinates x and y, in a previous question i had to generate a list of his neighbours and now I have to generate randomly his one of these neighbours and the result have to be in the form of (x,y) and only a single value.

```
import random 
#Qst1
cell=(2,3)
lgn, col = cell
def voisines_PI(cell):
    n=[(lgn-1,col-1),(lgn-1,col+1),(lgn+1,col+1),(lgn+1,col-1)]
    return n
print(voisines_PI(cell))

#Qst2

def voisine_PI_alea(cell):
    m= 0
    b= len(voisines_PI(cell))
    g= random.randint(m,b)
    return g
print(voisine_PI_alea(voisines_PI(cell)))
```

Comment: Looks like you already have the list of neighbors, so just `return random.choice(n)`. (Though shouldn't there be 8 neighbors?)

Comment: Also, don't hard-code the numbers 2 and 3. Use: `lgn, col = cell`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp depends on if diagonals are considered adjacent or not, I guess

Comment: @Dash All OP has now are the diagonals. Maybe that's the requirement??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @JohnnyMopp said, the function already returns a list of neighbors, so you can use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/random.html#random.choice) to select a random element of the list, like so:

```py
def voisine_PI_alea(cell):
    return random.choice(voisines_PI(cell))
```

Comment: and for making a rom liste of this result i tried this :